# Storing data submitted from users

Tags: php, mysql, data-storage

I am creating a site that will be hosting lists for the users. They will be able to access these lists and then make sub-lists that can also be saved/shared/whatever.

I am trying to figure out the best way to handle this data. My first thought is to make every user their own table in MySQL and store the relevant info there. If this turns out to be the best option, a pointer towards an article that you know of that covers this would be much appreciated.

If MySQL is not the best rout, what would you suggest?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple DataBase layout :

```
TableUser: 
    UserId
    UserName
    OtherInfos

TableListUser:
    ListUserId
    ListId
    UserId

TableList:
    ListId
    ListProprety

TableListItem:
    ListItemId
    ListId
    ListInfos
```

Normaly MySQL should work, but that depens a lot on the size of the data, the number of user, the number of requests/seconds .... That is your call.

Comment: The data will simply be text. The idea is to have a main repository that sublists can be  created from. I am just having some trouble visualizing how the tables should be set up, and I am having trouble finding help since it is difficult to phrase what I am looking to do in terms general enough for a search to do me any good.

Answer (score 0):

MySql is the way to go but you don't want to create one table for each user. You only need one certain table to store all the users.

What kind of lists do you want the users to access/create?

Comment: @alvero Each user would have a list of items that they create. Then they will create any number of sublists using their master list.<br/>I already have the master list for each user set up on one table, with each item having a field that matches the user who crated it's id#.<br/>The part I am having trouble with is how to store the sublists.